# Remove data below a completely blank row

Tags: r, subset

I have some data output from a machine stored in our group's working folder that is complicated. In order to start working, I started doing a lot of excel copy and paste and scrolling.

I need to write a reproducible script in R to clean and export the data. If the settings on the machine's software were set to export all variables I would get a csv dataset with a variable number of rows for each section like this...

```
Machine Test Database Output,,,,,,
,,,,,,
Created: 15:49:13 PM on Thursday February 15 1998,,,,,,
Objects Selected For Output:,,,,,,
1,1101(FIELD)->Red(TYPE)->AD(FILE),,,,,
2,240(FIELD)->Generic(TYPE)->AE0118(FILE),,,,,
3,248(FIELD)->Generic(TYPE)->AE0118(FILE),,,,,
,,,,,,
Pos,Num,Type,Month,Day,Year,Diam(in)
,,,,,,
1,1,26,10,20,2015,2.613159
1,2,26,10,20,2015,2.541779
1,3,26,10,20,2015,2.758759
,,,,,,
Mean Values:,,,,,,
Pos,Num,Type,Month,Day,Year,Diam(in)
1,5,26,10,20,2015,2.509277
2,5,1,8,30,2012,2.839154
3,15,1,6.666667,23,2012.333374,2.381047
,,,,,,
Standard Deviations:,,,,,,
Pos,Num,Type,Month,Day,Year,Diam(in)
1,5,0,0,0,0,0.174324
2,5,0,0,0,0,0.260001
```

What I have done so far is use `fread` from the `data.table` package in R to get to the top of the main data (side question...Eventually I need to make a script to turn the metadata into a key and replace the `Pos` numbers, adding the field type and file)

```
#skipping metadata
data1 <- fread("Data/digidata.csv",skip="  Pos")
```

But I still have variable number of rows between the start of the main data and the sd and mean data. What I need help doing is in removing/exporting the mean and standard deviation data from the main data. They are each separated by a blank row. I have seen ways to remove blank rows using `!`, but I don't want to remove blank rows, I need to subset each of the four sections into 4 dataframes. Any ideas?

Comment: Flag these rows then use `split` to generate 4 different text chunks of interest. Try `split(data1, cumsum(data1==',,,,,,'))`

Comment: Sorry @AdamO I am not sure how to flag rows. Can this be scripted for any size dataset? All of the commas don't appear after the data has been read in with `fread`. Would you mind spelling out how the functions work in your suggestion for an amateur R guy like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given AdamO's suggestion and a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000380/splitting-dataframes-in-r-based-on-empty-rows) that was found with a good answer. This is adapted from the answer to that question given by @sinQueso.

Split the output which has been read in as a dataframe `rawdata`

```
# add column to indicate groups
rawdata$tbl_id <- cumsum(!nzchar(rawdata$Machine.Database.Output))

## remove blank lines
rawdata <- rawdata[nzchar(rawdata$Machine.Test.Database.Output), ]

## split the data frame
dt_s <- split(rawdata[, -ncol(rawdata)], rawdata$tbl_id)

## use first line as header and reset row numbers
dt_s <- lapply(dt_s, function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- x[1, ]
  x <- x[-1, ]
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x
})

##to send all list parts out to their own dataframe
list2env(x=dt_s, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```