# Split dataframe by empty row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to split a horrendously formatted dataframe into a list of dataframes based on the rows of NA's between blocks i.e. Loc_1, Loc_2, Loc_3. I've tried [Splitting dataframes in R based on empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000380/splitting-dataframes-in-r-based-on-empty-rows) and [Divide or split dataframe into multiple dfs based on empty row and header title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718774/divide-or-split-dataframe-into-multiple-dfs-based-on-empty-row-and-header-title) with no luck. I think the difference in my case is I haven't got a single col without an NA value, as each new chunk starts with NAs for two rows in the first two columns, and there are loads of NAs scattered throughout. Any ideas? This is my first post, so please shout if I need to post more info!

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(NA, NA, "Loc_1", "Loc_1", "Loc_1", NA, NA, NA, "Loc_2", "Loc_2", "Loc_2", NA, NA, NA, "Loc_3", "Loc_3", "Loc_3"),
  b = c(NA, NA, "25:11:2020", "26:11:2020", "27:11:2020", NA, NA, NA, "25:11:2020", "26:11:2020", "27:11:2020",NA, NA, NA, "25:11:2020", "26:11:2020", "27:11:2020"),
  c = c("Var1", "Unit/1", 1:3, NA, "Var3", "Unit/3", NA, 1, 2, NA,"Var1", "Unit/1", 1:3),
  d = c("Var2", "Unit/2", NA, NA, 1, NA, "Var1", "Unit/1", NA, NA, 1, NA, "Var3", "Unit/3", NA, NA, 1)
)
```

```
       a          b      c      d
1   <NA>       <NA>   Var1   Var2
2   <NA>       <NA> Unit/1 Unit/2
3  Loc_1 25:11:2020      1   <NA>
4  Loc_1 26:11:2020      2   <NA>
5  Loc_1 27:11:2020      3      1
6   <NA>       <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
7   <NA>       <NA>   Var3   Var1
8   <NA>       <NA> Unit/3 Unit/1
9  Loc_2 25:11:2020   <NA>   <NA>
10 Loc_2 26:11:2020      1   <NA>
11 Loc_2 27:11:2020      2      1
12  <NA>       <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
13  <NA>       <NA>   Var1   Var3
14  <NA>       <NA> Unit/1 Unit/3
15 Loc_3 25:11:2020      1   <NA>
16 Loc_3 26:11:2020      2   <NA>
17 Loc_3 27:11:2020      3      1
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, new to this, the answer 27 ϕ 9 is how I had originally expected it was going to look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this Base R solution:

```
n <- rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df)
cs <- cumsum(n) + 1
s <- split(df[!n, ], cs[!n])

s

#> $`1`
#>       a          b      c      d
#> 1  <NA>       <NA>   Var1   Var2
#> 2  <NA>       <NA> Unit/1 Unit/2
#> 3 Loc_1 25:11:2020      1   <NA>
#> 4 Loc_1 26:11:2020      2   <NA>
#> 5 Loc_1 27:11:2020      3      1
#> 
#> $`2`
#>        a          b      c      d
#> 7   <NA>       <NA>   Var3   Var1
#> 8   <NA>       <NA> Unit/3 Unit/1
#> 9  Loc_2 25:11:2020   <NA>   <NA>
#> 10 Loc_2 26:11:2020      1   <NA>
#> 11 Loc_2 27:11:2020      2      1
#> 
#> $`3`
#>        a          b      c      d
#> 13  <NA>       <NA>   Var1   Var3
#> 14  <NA>       <NA> Unit/1 Unit/3
#> 15 Loc_3 25:11:2020      1   <NA>
#> 16 Loc_3 26:11:2020      2   <NA>
#> 17 Loc_3 27:11:2020      3      1
```

---

You can neatly set all your data together again in a long format in this way with `unpivotr`:

```
library(unpivotr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_dfr(s, 
        ~ as_cells(.x) %>% 
         behead("up", "var") %>% 
         behead("up", "uom") %>% 
         behead("left", "loc") %>% 
         behead("left", "date") %>% 
         # filter(!is.na(chr)) %>%  # do you need the NAs?
         mutate(value = as.numeric(chr)) %>% 
         select(var, uom, loc, date, value),
        .id = "df")

#> # A tibble: 18 x 6
#>    df    var   uom    loc   date       value
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 1     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_1 25:11:2020     1
#>  2 1     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_1 26:11:2020     2
#>  3 1     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_1 27:11:2020     3
#>  4 1     Var2  Unit/2 Loc_1 25:11:2020    NA
#>  5 1     Var2  Unit/2 Loc_1 26:11:2020    NA
#>  6 1     Var2  Unit/2 Loc_1 27:11:2020     1
#>  7 2     Var3  Unit/3 Loc_2 25:11:2020    NA
#>  8 2     Var3  Unit/3 Loc_2 26:11:2020     1
#>  9 2     Var3  Unit/3 Loc_2 27:11:2020     2
#> 10 2     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_2 25:11:2020    NA
#> 11 2     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_2 26:11:2020    NA
#> 12 2     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_2 27:11:2020     1
#> 13 3     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_3 25:11:2020     1
#> 14 3     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_3 26:11:2020     2
#> 15 3     Var1  Unit/1 Loc_3 27:11:2020     3
#> 16 3     Var3  Unit/3 Loc_3 25:11:2020    NA
#> 17 3     Var3  Unit/3 Loc_3 26:11:2020    NA
#> 18 3     Var3  Unit/3 Loc_3 27:11:2020     1
```

If you don't want one unique dataframe at the end, use `map` instead of `map_dfr` and remove `, .id = "df"`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! And thanks for sorting out my next step in wrangling it into some sort of useful format! I've not come across unpivotr before (normally use dplyr::pivot_longer) so that's really useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(grp = cumsum(rowSums(is.na(.)) == ncol(.)), .keep = FALSE) %>%
  map_at(.at = -1, tail, -1)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  a     b          c      d     
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr> 
1 NA    NA         Var1   Var2  
2 NA    NA         Unit/1 Unit/2
3 Loc_1 25:11:2020 1      NA    
4 Loc_1 26:11:2020 2      NA    
5 Loc_1 27:11:2020 3      1     

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  a     b          c      d     
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr> 
1 NA    NA         Var3   Var1  
2 NA    NA         Unit/3 Unit/1
3 Loc_2 25:11:2020 NA     NA    
4 Loc_2 26:11:2020 1      NA    
5 Loc_2 27:11:2020 2      1     

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  a     b          c      d     
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr> 
1 NA    NA         Var1   Var3  
2 NA    NA         Unit/1 Unit/3
3 Loc_3 25:11:2020 1      NA    
4 Loc_3 26:11:2020 2      NA    
5 Loc_3 27:11:2020 3      1
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, this is what I was after too! I'll probably use this in combo with the other answer for the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your desired output. Here is my best guess. I added more code trying to remove the first two rows for each `loc` as those are just column names, and then assign the new column names based on the original first row. This additional step allows you to convert the `Var` columns to numeric.

```
library(tidyverse)

# A helper function to filter rows with any non-NA values
rowAny <- function(x) rowSums(x) > 0

df_list <- df %>%
  # Remove rows with all NA
  filter(rowAny(across(everything(), .fns = function(x) !is.na(x)))) %>%
  # Fill the Loc information
  fill(a, .direction = "up") %>%
  # Split the data frame by a
  split(.$a) %>%
  # Remove the first two rows and change the column names to the first row (Var1, Var2, Var3, ...)
  map(function(x){
    
    # Prepare new column names
    x2 <- x %>% 
      slice(1) %>%
      t() %>%
      as.vector()
    
    x_names <- c(names(x)[1:2], x2[3:length(x2)])
    
    # Remove the first two rows and assign new column names
    x3 <- x %>%
      slice(-1:-2) %>%
      set_names(x_names) %>%
      # Change the columns to numeric
      mutate(across(x2[3:length(x2)], .fns = as.numeric))
    
    return(x3)
  })

df_list
# $Loc_1
#       a          b Var1 Var2
# 1 Loc_1 25:11:2020    1   NA
# 2 Loc_1 26:11:2020    2   NA
# 3 Loc_1 27:11:2020    3    1
# 
# $Loc_2
#       a          b Var3 Var1
# 1 Loc_2 25:11:2020   NA   NA
# 2 Loc_2 26:11:2020    1   NA
# 3 Loc_2 27:11:2020    2    1
# 
# $Loc_3
#       a          b Var1 Var3
# 1 Loc_3 25:11:2020    1   NA
# 2 Loc_3 26:11:2020    2   NA
# 3 Loc_3 27:11:2020    3    1
```